# getting the error "unsupported version" when trying to open realm database

Tags: swift, realm

When I try to open realm browser with simulator running I'm getting the error "unsupported version".

[image]

Yet the realm database opens fine after I stop running the application.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a version of Realm Browser that's older than the version of Realm you're using in your application then there may be incompatibilities. Please ensure that you have the most recent version of the Realm Browser application, currently v0.98.5.

Comment: it looks like they just updated browser today. thank you!!